# onItemClick not being invoked on ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, onitemclicklistener

I have a class that extends from `ListActivity` and implements `OnItemClickListener`

It's a very simple test class, the idea is that I select an item on the list, and it shows the selected item on a `Toast`.

I can see the list normally on the emulator, and I can also see the effects of clicking in the item, but then nothing happens.

I don't think the event is being fired, because I see nothing on LogCat, here's the code:

```
public class CarsListActivity extends ListActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listCars()));
    }

    private List<String> listCars() {   
        return Arrays.asList("Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Porsche");
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        String message = "Selected car: " + textView.getText();
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The `Activitiy` is defined like this on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".CarsListActivity" />
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

I researched this error and I found many solutions saying that this concerns clickability and focusability attributes on the layout. But I'm using Android's own `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` so I don't really know how I could fix it.

Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Is your list item really a simple `TextView`? Isn't it a `LinearLayout` or something? Because if it's `LinearLayout` then you can not cast it to a `TextView`...

Comment: Maybe You have to set ListView on itemClickListener by  ListView v = getListView(); and then v.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Comment: Yeah, that was it @Opiatefuchs. Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: According to the official doc you should be implemmenting `onListItemClick` instead of `onItemClick` that means you won't need to declare `implements OnItemClickListener`. Take a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to register the OnItemClickListener (the activity) like this :

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this)
```

Simply implementing the OnItemClickListener interface is not sufficient

Comment: Wow, don't I feel stupid now :) That was it. I'll accept your answer when StackOverflow allows me to. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a common mistake don't worry about it :) But you'll probably remember it from now on :)

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki, Shouldn't you be using `onListItemClick` instead of implementing `OnItemClickListener`?

Comment: I'm not really sure, @yugidroid. I'm following the examples from a book I bought. I'm really just starting to learn. I'll have a look at the link you posted above anyway :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both are valid options. The OnItemClickListener provides a slightly more loosely coupled solution as it's just part of an interface and doesn't tie you into the ListActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

add this in onCreate() below setListAdapter()

```
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

use this on `oncreate()`

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
```